# inserting into a mongodb collection with manually specified _id

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have a collection in mongodb and the objects in the collection have an _id that is an ObjectID that I selected in some random manner completely external to mongoDB, such as starting with ObjectID 0000 ... 0000 and incrementing by 10000, or maybe just used a random number generator to make the ObjectID's.

Suppose I then go to add another item to the collection, but I don't have an ObjectID in mind for the new object, and am satisfied with letting the system pick one.  Would the system ever select a ObjectID that was already a part of the collection?

If it is relevant, I am using the java API and the python API to do this.

Comment: `letting the system pick one` - By "system", do you mean the mongoDB server or the id generator API?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know which component of the system actually generates the new ObjectID.  For example, I know that if I insert something in java the inserted object gets an ObjectID added to it, but I don't know whether the server generates the OjbectID, or if the API generates the ObjectID.

Answer (score 0):

`_id` is always unique. There's an implicit unique primary index on `_id` field.

So rest assured that MongoDB will not choose an `_id` field that has been taken.

Also the `_id` field is a 12 byte hexadecimal string in which :

- 4 bytes is for the date timestamp.
- 3 bytes is the MAC Address.
- 2 bytes is the process id.
- 3 bytes is the counter.

So if MongoDB chooses an _id for your document in a collection, it's definitely going to be unique from the other _id fields in other documents in your collection.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I am generating random ObjectID's what prevents me from randomly generating an ObjectID that MongoDB would generate if left to its own devices?  For example, suppose that time bytes in the timestamp happened to match, the bytes in the mac address happened to match, the bytes in the process id happened to match, and the bytes for the counter were such that they happened to correspond to the bytes that would be present in the counter?  Does mongoDB notice this and select a different ObjectID when handing out new ObjectID's?

Comment: Ummmm... no it doesn't. It's going to give you an error if you have to assign an _id to a document that's already the _id of some other document, in the same collection.

Comment: It's extremely rare, almost impossible for the system to create a duplicate _id on its own. As far as your randomly generated _id is concerned, I don't think you'll be able to match the _id that you created with that created by mongodb.